# How to stop autoplaying youtube iframe video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I do have an embedded youtube iframe video, which is autoplaying on click. Now, I have to stop this autoplaying iframe video while clicking on outside(window) or close button. I have tried multiple things, but both scenario is not working together, like if video would get stop then, autoplay will not work & vice versa. Following is my code.

// This is the case when video is getting stopped on clicking outside, but autoplay is not working

```
<div id="modalVideo" class="modal fade">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                    aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                <img alt="Brand" src="{{ 'logo@2x.png' | asset_url }}" height="20">
                            </div>
                            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="560" height="315"
                                    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aqkGCzcx34A?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer&autoplay=1"
                                    frameborder="0"
                                    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                                    allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

<script>
$(window).click(function () {
        $('.embed-responsive-item')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
    });
</script>
```

// This is the case when autoplay is working, but video is not getting stopped

```
<div id="modalVideo" class="modal fade">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                    aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                <img alt="Brand" src="{{ 'logo@2x.png' | asset_url }}" height="20">
                            </div>
                            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="560" height="315"
                                    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aqkGCzcx34A?autoplay=1"
                                    frameborder="0"
                                    allow="autoplay"
                                    allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

<script>
$(window).click(function () {
        $('.embed-responsive-item')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
    });
</script>
```

Kindly help me out if you guys have faced similar situation or problem.

Comment: `"I have tried multiple things"` - have you tried the YouTube API? It has methods for pausing/stopping videos: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: yes, I have tried player.stopVideo() method. But, the video will get started again as autoplay is also there.

Comment: What about removing `autoplay` and using `playVideo()` method when the video's loaded (i.e. `onReady`)?